# "his reason caught up with his senses" meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> For a split second Harry thought he had done magic without meaning to, despite the fact that he'd been resisting as hard as he could—then **his reason caught up with his senses**—he didn't have the power to turn off the stars. He turned his head this way and that, trying to see something, but the darkness pressed on his eyes like a weightless veil.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

I am not sure about the meaning of "his reason caught up with his senses". I think it probably means: *Harry's reason became as realistic as his senses, that is, he got it reasonably now(he didn't have the power to turn off the stars)*. How should we understand it if my understanding is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine it as a running competition.

At first, Harry's senses got ahead of his reason. His senses (eyesight/hearing/feeling etc.) told Harry that he might have turned off the stars.

Then, his reason (his brain) caught up with his senses, and told Harry "no, don't listen to your senses! Think! You don't have the power to turn off the stars".

A human's senses are quicker than his reason, so it takes some time for the reason to **catch up** in a particular situation. And until the reason has caught up, the senses make one believe in all kinds of odd things, like turning off the stars.